# Passing Enum Array or list to Function

Tags: vb.net, linq

I want to compare an enum array to single enum instance.

**Introduction**

I have a class with an enum type array\list

```
Public Enum InvalidEmailType
    Multiple_Updates  
    Period_Before_At_Sign
    Missing_Dot_Com
End Enum
Public Class CustomerClass
    Public CustomerName As String
    Public ErrorTypeList = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(InvalidEmailType))
    Public ErrorDescription As String
End Class
```

Depending on what values are added to the list, I want to run specific code.

In order to do this I compare the entire list to a single instance:

```
        If UpdateCustomer.MatchErrorType(customer.ErrorTypeList, InvalidEmailType.Trailing_Period) = True Then
            'Run Code
        End If
```

Inside the function I compare the entire list against the single instance.

In other words, I loop through the entire list inside the class and check if the value is there:

```
Public Shared Function MatchErrorType(CustomerErrortypeList As List(Of InvalidEmailType), EmailError As InvalidEmailType) As Boolean
    MatchErrorType = False
    Dim Found As InvalidEmailType = CustomerErrortypeList.Where(Function(match) match.ToString = EmailError.ToString).OrderByDescending(Function(match) match.ToString).FirstOrDefault()
    If Found > 0 Then
        MatchErrorType = True
    End If
End Function
```

**Here is the problem:**
How do I declare the array\list in the function parameters?

List(Of InvalidEmailType) does not work, as I get a cast error

**Unable to cast object of type 'EmailValidationReport.InvalidEmailType[]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EmailValidationReport.InvalidEmailType]'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ErrorTypeList to a `List(of InvalidEmailType)` instead of array.

```
Public ErrorTypeList = [Enum].GetValues(GetType(InvalidEmailType)) _
                       .Cast(of InvalidEmailType)().ToList()
```

or

```
Dim list = customer.ErrorTypeList.Cast(of InvalidEmailType)().ToList()
If UpdateCustomer.MatchErrorType(list, InvalidEmailType.Trailing_Period) Then
    'Run Code
End If
```

Comment: the list is contained inside the customer class

Comment: @InternetEngineer ok, you can do it before you call the function also, see updated answer.

Comment: The cast does not work:   
Public member 'Cast' on type 'InvalidEmailType()' not found

Comment: You need to import System.Linq

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't doing anything that is specific to `List` or `Array`, you can make your method signature take in an `IEnumerable` instead of a `List`.  This should be able to handle both `List` and `Array` (and a few more types as well).

```
Public Shared Function MatchErrorType(CustomerErrortypeList As IEnumerable(Of InvalidEmailType), EmailError As InvalidEmailType) As Boolean
    Dim Found As InvalidEmailType = CustomerErrortypeList.Where(Function(match) match.ToString = EmailError.ToString).OrderByDescending(Function(match) match.ToString).FirstOrDefault()
    MatchErrorType = (Found > 0)
End Function
```